# Cannot extend from interface CompilerPassInterface in Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, overriding, fosuserbundle

I want to override the controller (RegistartionController) of FosUserbundle by the using of compilerPass in Symfony 3.4 so this is my code

*=== RegisterUserCompilerPass ===*

```
<?php

namespace myBundle;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;


class RegisterUserCompilerPass extends CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container
            ->getDefinition('fos_user.registration.controller')
            ->setClass(MyBundle\Controller\ReplaceRegistrationController::class) ; 
    }
}
```

and this is file when add add it to the main bundle class

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle;


use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

use MyBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\RegisterUserCompilerPass  ; 


// use Crypto\UserBundle\Manager\ReplaceRegistration ; 

class CryptoUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
     parent::build($container);
       $container->addCompilerPass(new RegisterUserCompilerPass() );
    }

}
```

when access to my register path i get

> Compile Error: Class
>   MyBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\RegisterUserCompilerPass cannot
>   extend from interface
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface

Comment: You should understand your error messages, not just read them, it will make your life simpler :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class RegisterUserCompilerPass extends CompilerPassInterface
```

should be

```
class RegisterUserCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
```

See [PHP can't extend from interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829996/php-cant-extend-from-interface)

Comment: You should explain why even if the answer is basic.